# How can i see the entries stored by mongoose using mongo's shell?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and i have a schema called MessageSchema which i use through a MessageModel to store messages in a database.

This is already working as i can save instances and retrieve them using MessageModel.find(...)

I'm running mongodb and nodejs on Windows. So, when i start the mongo shell by executing "mongo" in a cmd window and try to do:

```
use mydb
db.mydb.find()
```

nothing comes up.

How can i see these entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current command you are switching to your database but then you are trying to query a collection called `mydb` in your `mydb` database. When you type `use mydb` you are making the `db` object point to your database. Now you have access to the collections in that databse using

```
db.<collection>.find()
```

The correct command you want to use would be

```
use mydb;
db.MessageModel.find();
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Just one thing, instead of db.MessageModel it is db.messagemodels.find(). Besides that it's correct :) I just found out while testing with your answer and using the autocomplete.